# Android progressdialog SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

In my app I manage a lot of data and I view them in a listview.
Data are many I'm afraid that some device in the opening of Activity is slow ...
I would like to add a progress dialog for loading the data before displaying it.
Do you have any example for this?`

```
private void showDetails(String anno){
    SQLiteDatabase db = new BilancioHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
    final List<Dettaglio> dettagli = new ArrayList<Euscite.Dettaglio>(12);

    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++){
        String mese;
        if (i<10){
            mese = "0"+i;
        } else {
            mese = ""+i;
        }

        String sql = "SELECT _Id,Data,Categoria,Note,Uscita FROM Giornate WHERE uscita>0 AND data LIKE '"+anno+"-"+mese+"%'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()){
            Dettaglio d = new Dettaglio();
            d.id = c.getInt(0);
            d.data = c.getString(1);
            d.categorie = ( c.getString(2) != null ) ? c.getString(2) : "";
            d.note = ( c.getString(3) != null ) ? c.getString(3) : "";
            d.uscite = c.getFloat(4);


            dettagli.add(d);
        }
        c.close();
    }

    db.close();

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dettaglio>(this, R.layout.dettaglio_row_uscite, R.id.tv_entrata, dettagli){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            Log.v("Bilancio", "Creo elemento in posizione "+position);


            TextView tvData, tvNote, tvUscite, tvId, tvCategorie;
            tvData = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_data_uscita);


            tvUscite = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_entrata);
            tvCategorie = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_cat_uscite);
            tvNote = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_note_us);

            tvId = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_id_uscite);

            Dettaglio d = dettagli.get(position);
            tvData.setText(d.data+"");
            tvNote.setText(d.note+"");  
            tvCategorie.setText(d.categorie+"");

            Double value = Double.valueOf(d.uscite);
            NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            String uscite = formatter.format(value );
            tvUscite.setText(uscite+"");

            tvId.setText(d.id+"");
            return row;
        }
    };
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for AsyncTasks
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It's pretty simple: You implement a class with AsyncTask as it's superclass and override the three methods:

The `onPreExecute()`-method should show a `ProgressDialog`

The `doInBackground(Context... arg0)`-method collects the data from the database.

The `onPostExecute(String result)`-method puts the data into the list and closes the `ProgressDialog`

In your code you should split your method into two: The first one (let's call it `getData()`) from the start to `db.close();` and everything after that in the second method (for example `showData()`)

Then you create a class in your activity like this:

```
protected class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String>
{
ProgressDialog myLoadingDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
myLoadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
myLoadingDialog.setMessage("Loading");
    myLoadingDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    myLoadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
    myLoadingDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Context... arg0)
{
    getData();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    showData();
    myLoadingDialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
}
```

Put the variables outside of the methods, which you need in both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Or a CursorLoader: [Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html), which allows you to reload the data when it changes.

One way of showing progress while doing a background task is to use an AsyncTask. Another way is to use a ProgressBar widget that starts out invisible (android:visibility="gone") when the app first starts. When you start the data load, you set it to visible ((android:visibility="visible"). When the data load finishes, you set it back to "gone". "Gone" is better than "invisible", because "gone" removes the widget from the view calculations, as if it weren't part of the layout. "Invisible" won't show the widget, but it will show the space that the widget takes up.