# Set the progress bar value from database

Tags: android, mysql, progress-bar

Is it possible to set the progress value of ProgressBar in Android based on data entered in database?

For example, if the user have goal of 150 steps. She/He already got 55 steps, then I want to display it in circular progress bar (55/150) . And also, same when he/she got another 50(for example), the progress bar will update.

I am asking this because I can't find any tutorials regarding this (or maybe I missed). Please help me.

Comment: just adapt this code, you only need to update the value from database https://demonuts.com/circular-progress-bar/

Comment: yeah thanks @JoaquinAlvarez . Can you give me some idea on how to start?? I know how to create the progressbar, and also I tried the link you gave me, I just wanted to know how to connect it to database(value) , I really have no idea.

Comment: it all depends on wich database are you using

Comment: yeah. Okay, let's say , is there any tutorials you know on how to connect db to progress bar, I can't find one :( is it really possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create database or `SharedPreferences` and every time save and get(then set) progress from it.

for `SharedPreferences` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

if you want local database you can use `SQLite`
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java

if you want normal database from hosting you can use `MySQL` and relate that `MySQL` database to your android via `PHP` file by for example `post` method of `StringRequest`

if you don't know how to set progress bar, just `setProgress(int)`
more about progress bar https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress(int)

Comment: thanks @Java Rzayev . I am using MySQL as my database, perhaps can you give some snippet or code on how to **set** the progress value connected to database?? I really have no idea.

Comment: @Shasha as I understand you don't know how to connect mysql data base with android application.  You can connect it by PHP file. get/post methods. I found for you good tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm , but I use another way in php file I convert my data from mysql to JSONobject and send to android  then in. android receive it by any class which `extends StringRequest` .  But after getting data from mysql the way of setting data to progress bar is easy just  by `setProgress(int dataFromMySQL)`

Comment: ahh, I am now slowly getting the idea. thank you @Java Rzayev. One more hint please, in `setProgress(int dataFromMySQL)` how should I create a `dataFromMySQL` function/class ??? **PS**: I know how to connect the db to android and I am using JSON.

Comment: @Shasha I should now your database, but for example you have simply database  with table `your_table` with 2 columns (users(primary key) and current_progress), and you want to get progress from database for user (for example John) , then by `Post` method you sent String John to `php` file , where you are connected to database and  then make simply query `SELECT current_progress FROM your_table WHERE user = John` , and then result of that query sent to your app by `JSON encoding` and in app you will get that `JSONObject` and can set that result to your progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on both links below:

[Progress-dialog-while-loading-database-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953876/showing-progress-dialog-while-loading-database-in-android)

[Android progress dialog SqLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039241/android-progressdialog-sqlite)

Hope it helps

Comment: sorry, maybe you misunderstand my question @Igor, I wanted to display the data from database to progress bar value. Let's say, I have 150 value coming from the database, now I wanted to display it in progress bar.

Comment: probably you have to create a custom progress bar where you can change values according with you need. 
look here if it helps: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409912/android-how-to-update-value-of-progressbar